# (Pre-calculus) How do I factor the following expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The following identity is required to be factorized:

$3p^2 - 3p - 36$

What method do I use, and how would I go on about doing this?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, rewrite it as $$3(p^2 - p - 12).$$

Now, you just have to factorize $p^2-p-12$. For this, you want to write
$$p^2-p-12=(p-a)(p-b).$$

Using Vieto's rules, you know that the $a$ and $b$ must be such that $ab=-12$ and $a+b=-1$. Such $a$ and $b$ are not particularly difficult to find.

Comment: Thank you, I have got it. I am familiar with this rule, but how would I identify the fact that, I would need to use this rule? There are ways such as difference of squares, difference of cubes etc when do I use which?

Comment: You won't like the answer, but it's the only one I can give: through practice. You will get used to it. In general, when the function is a square polynomial, $Ax^2+Bx+C$, you use Vieto. If it does not contain a $b$ ($Ax^2+C$), then you use difference of squares (which is basically the same as Vieto since $a+b=B=0$. You only use difference of cubes once you actually have cubes. 

Trust me, these rules come naturaly with practice. A LOT of practice.

Comment: Thanks, that is just what I needed to hear. I'll try a few more problems then on.

Answer (score 2):

Note that all terms are divisible by 3, so the first (easiest thing) you can do is to pull out a *common factor.* Like so:

$3(p^2 - p - 12)$

You can verify that the value of the expression has not changed by distributing the 3 back in. The great thing about factoring is that you can always check your work in this manner.

Now let's focus inside the brackets. When multiplying out two simple binomials, such as:

$(x + a)(x + b)$

You'll get:

$x^2 + ax + bx + ab$

Note that two terms contain $x^1$ (or just $x$), so they can be added to get:

$x^2 + (a+b)x + ab$

The previous line is the situation you find yourself with when trying to factor $(p^2 - p - 12)$.

From this expression we must try and deduce the values of a and b in order to factor our expression into $(x + a)(x + b)$ form. This sounds tricky, but there a few clever tricks that can really aid us:

The first thing to notice is that the last constant term ($-12$) is negative. If multiplying a*b yields a negative number, we know that they must be different signs. (if they were both positive, their product would be positive; if they were both negative, their negatives would cancel to yield a positive product). So we know that $a$ and $b$ are different signs.

The second thing to note is that the coefficient of $p^1$ (or just $p$) is negative. Because we already learned that a and b are of different signs, we can conclude that the negative number is greater. (for example, $3 + (-5)$ is negative because the negative number has a greater absolute value (its value ignoring the sign) than the positive number)

So far we know that two numbers, a, b must sum to produce the coefficient of $p^1$ ($-1$) and multiply to get the coefficient of $p^0$ (the constant term; $-12$).

For a moment we'll ignore the signs. In order for two integers to multiply to 12, they must be factors of 12. We can see that there are only a few factors we can try:

$12 = 1 * 12$

$12 = 2 * 6$

$12 = 3 * 4$

We know that the difference between the correct set of factors has to be 1 (in order for the middle term to work out), so we can look at the differences between the sets of factors:

$12 - 1 = 11$ not 1, so it's no good.

$6 - 2 = 4$ still not 1.

$4 - 3 = 1$ one! This is the correct pair of factors.

Now to properly apply the signs: we've established that the two factors must have opposite signs, with the negative factors absolute value being greater. Since 4 is greater than 3, 4 must be the negative number, leaving the 3 to be positive.

$a = 3$

$b = -4$

Now we can factor the expression:

$(p^2 - p - 12)$

$= p^2-4p+3p-12$

$= p(p-4)+3(p-4)$

$= (p - 4)(p + 3)$

*Note: at this point it's a good idea to try and multiply is out, to verify your work.*

Putting it all together, we conclude that:

$3p^2 - 3p - 36$

$= 3(p^2 - p - 12)$

$= 3(p - 4)(p + 3)$

Comment: Just to note, I know this is quite long, but I wanted it to be detailed for high-schoolers stumbling upon this from Google

Comment: anddddddd ofc I make a mistake on the thing I explicitly say should be checked -.-'

Comment: Thanks for writing this up, it definitely helped paint a clearer picture in my head. Much appreciated.